# Escape XML not considering the namespace using XSLT and getting ignored (using Mule XSLT component)

Tags: xml, xslt, escaping

I'm trying to escape part of the xml and using XSLT script i got through the stackflow i was able to escape the particular node but the name space is getting ignored.  The sample example as below

```
<root>
   <parent>test</parent>
   <parentdtl>
   <child xmlns="http://test.com">
       <element1>1</element1>
   </child>   
   </parentdtl>
   <outer>T</outer>
</root>
```

Using the XSLT code

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
xmlns="http://test.com">
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no">&lt;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="name()"  />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"  />
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no">&gt;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no">&lt;/</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no">&gt;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="@*" >
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no">&#32;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="name()" disable-output-escaping="no"/>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">=&amp;quot;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="no"/>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;quot;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="root|parent|parentdtl|outer">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But the output is received with out the name space as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root>
   <parent>test</parent>
   <parentdtl>
   &lt;child&gt;
       &lt;element1&gt;1&lt;/element1&gt;
   &lt;/child&gt;   
   </parentdtl>
   <outer>T</outer>
</root>
```

Please let me know if I need to add any logic to include the namespace

Comment: Which XSLT processor do you use? XSLT 3 processors support a `serialize` function and XSLT 2 or even some XSLT 1 processors have proprietary extensions or allow you to implement them easily as extension functions.

Comment: I'm working on Mule ESB tool and not sure what is the internal processor it uses. But i'm trying the same using the below link as well, http://xsltransform.net/gWvjQeV , any xsl script logic using version 2.0 will be helpful in my case

Comment: Check the output of `<xsl:value-of select="concat(' Product ', system-property('xsl:product-name'), ' ', system-property('xsl:product-version'))"/>` to see which processor you have.

Comment: I got this information "Mule relies on Saxon HE which does not support streaming in XSLT transformation" . and Mule 3.6.0 and later versions support XSLT version 3.0 for the XSLT transformer. The transformer’s behavior and syntax remain unaltered from earlier versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With XSLT 3 support you can use the `serialize` function:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

   <xsl:template match="*">
       <xsl:value-of select="serialize(.)"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="root|parent|parentdtl|outer">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template> 
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jxN9PRK/1

For older (non XPath 3.1) versions of `serialize`  you might need

```
   <xsl:template match="*">
       <xsl:variable name="ser-params" as="element()">
          <output:serialization-parameters xmlns:output="http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization">
             <output:omit-xml-declaration value="yes"/>
          </output:serialization-parameters>
       </xsl:variable>
       <xsl:value-of select="serialize(., $ser-params)"/>
   </xsl:template>
```

to avoid the XML declaration.

Comment: Thank You @Martin Honnen, this worked fine. Just the following observations and wanted to clarify, is it possible to escape the quotes in the namespace uri or it should not be a problem as per standard?  And im seeing the xml header &lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?&gt; just before the start of escaped node in the IDE where i'm executing . can this be ignored using any property?

Comment: @Prasanth, inside element content neither a single nor a double quote needs to be escaped, you only need to escape a double quote in an attribute value delimited by double quotes or a single quote in an attribute value delimited by single quotes. As for the XML declaration, if you don't want that, try whether `<xsl:value-of select="serialize(., map { 'omit-xml-declaration' : true() })"/>` works and helps.

Comment: Thank You Martin, if i try with the map function following exception is thrown,  XPST0003 XPath syntax error at char 13 on line 6 near {..., map { 'omit-xml-declarati...}:
    map expressions require XPath 3.0/XQuery 3.0 to be enabled.

Comment: @Prasanth, and you can't use `version="3.0"` in your XSLT? Or do you have that? Have you found out by now which Saxon version exactly is in your version of Mule?

Comment: Hi @Martin, Version 3.0 works fine but i see some issue using the xapth 3.0 functions. Since this (Mule) is a product we don't have clear information on the internal engine version used. I will try to find out.

Comment: looking at the libraries in the project path i could see the version <version>9.9.1-2</version> of Saxon HE

Comment: @Prasanth, Saxon 9.9 is an XSLT 3 processor so you should be able to use `version="3.0"` and the suggestion `<xsl:value-of select="serialize(., map { 'omit-xml-declaration' : true() })"/>` should work.

Comment: Apologize I mentioned the wrong Saxon version. I had a look at the compilation stack trace and found it uses the 9.6 version of Saxon HE, et.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: Stylesheet compilation failed: 1 error reported
 at net.sf.saxon.style.Compilation.compileSingletonPackage(Compilation.java:97) ~[Saxon-HE-9.6.0-10.jar:?]
 at net.sf.saxon.s9api.XsltCompiler.compile(XsltCompiler.java:543) ~[Saxon-HE-9.6.0-10.jar:?]
 at net.sf.saxon.jaxp.SaxonTransformerFactory.newTemplates(SaxonTransformerFactory.java:152) ~[Saxon-HE-9.6.0-10.jar:?]

Comment: @Prasanth, I don't remember for sure which support Saxon 9.6 HE has for `serialize`, I think it will only support it with `version="3.0"`. As for the XML declaration to not be emitted when serializing an element, see the edit. But I haven't tested with Saxon 9.6, it is too old to have it available or to remember at which stage of a spec and implementation under development it was.